# Load an HTML5 Canvas to another HTML5 Canvas with Flash CC and CreateJS

Tags: html, createjs, flash-cc

Hi all I'm just curious , is it possible to load the HTML5 Canvas file into another HTML5 Canvas with Flash CC or CreateJS . If we can do that ( I really hope it's possible ) , How can I do it ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

The first is to consume the second canvas into a `Bitmap` object. This will paint it into your primary canvas, but if you have any mouse listeners in the second canvas, these will not function.

`var canvas2 = document.getElementById("mySecondCanvas");
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(canvas2);
myStage.addChild(bmp);`

If you'd like to maintain interactivity in the "sub" content, the best approach is to simply copy the display list over. If you're using content exported from Flash Pro, this is as easy as adding the `exportRoot` container. You may also want to add a `mask` to clip it to the original canvas dimensions.

`myStage.addChild(secondCanvasExportRoot);
mask = new createjs.Shape();
mask.graphics.rect(0,0,canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
secondCanvaCanvasExportRoot.mask = mask;`

If not, then just add or copy all of the elements on your second stage into a container on your primary stage.

Comment: Thank you gskinner, for your solutions .(sorry for my bad english) But what I want to do is to load the `.html` file (that published with Flash CC). e.g : I have a html5 file `MasterSlide.html` (and of course with the MasterSlide.js in the same folder). The MasterSlide will contains slides in it. I want to split the slide into each file like `slide1.html, slide2.html, ... etc`. So the MasterSlide will load each file into its canvas. I'm doing this because I want to save the performance when loading the html page (I have a dozens of slides). If this case is possible, how can I do that?